# print prn file using c# win forms

Tags: c#, winforms, printing, zebra-printers

I have a c# winforms project
want to print a prn file through zebra label printer

I tried cmd `copy  /b C:\Users\me\Desktop\zebra\print_3.prn "Zebra Test Printer"`
in cmd it says `1 file(s) copied.` but nothing going to printer or printer queue
instead a new file is being created same as printer name `Zebra Test Printer` withut any extension on desktop

In C# I listed all installed printer and chosen zebra printer and then trying below code
but here it gives below error

```
Process process1 = new Process();
process1.StartInfo.FileName = "copy";
string prnFile = "C:\Users\me\Desktop\zebra\print_3.prn";
string selectedPrinter =  "\"Zebra Test Printer\"";
process1.StartInfo.Arguments = " /b " + prnFile + " " + selectedPrinter;
process1.Start();
```

but this gives error below
`The system cannot find the file specified`

I am open to use any approach just want to print prn file using c#.

Comment: Maybe [this article](https://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1784519) can help you

Comment: You need to use the WinAPI to print or some C# wrapper for it. Afaik, the ``copy`` command works only for printers connected over ``COM`` or ``LPT`` port, and you have to use the port name in this case, not the Windows printer name.

Answer (score 0):

In C#, the following string literal `C:\Users\me\Desktop\zebra\print_3.prn`
is actually interpreted as
`"C:\\Users\\me\\Desktop\\zebra\\print_3.prn"`;

Add a double backslash or you can use the following syntax with the same result:

`string prnFile = @"C:\Users\me\Desktop\zebra\print_3.prn";`